# Reading the error body in PHP curl_exec

Tags: php, curl, httpresponse, http-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using PHP curl how does one get the response body for a 400 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363916/using-php-curl-how-does-one-get-the-response-body-for-a-400-response)

When using PHP's curl_exec to call a RESTful API the documentation says http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

When curl_exec fails it returns false.  However the remote server might have tried to return a helpful message to go with that error.  How can we access this message using curl_exec, when it just returns false?

For example the remote API might be returning this message and a HTTP 400 status code:

```
{"Items":[{"Field":"FirstName","Description":"FirstName is required and cannot be null."}]}
```

Currently I am unable to read this error message that has been returned, instead all I get is false.  I have looked at curl_info too.  I do have returntransfer set on.

In C# I would use the `exception.Response.GetResponseStream` method and write:

```
    private static string Post(WebClient client, string uri, string postData)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            response = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", postData);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream(); // here
            if (stream != null)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

How can this be done in PHP? Is curl_exec the right method or should I use something else?

Comment: looook http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: That just returns the string for whatever status code was returned, eg "Bad Request" for the http 400 I am getting.  It doesn't return the message set by the remote API.  Actually, no - I just checked again, curl_error is returning an empty string

Comment: @JK. I cant see any way of doing that except... sockets,

Comment: With `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);` and `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES, array(400));` set, $curl_result is only returning "Bad Request" (a small improvement - before it was returning false)

Comment: @JK. Sorry, what is `$curl_result`? The return value of `curl_exec()`?

Comment: @JK. Definitely working for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/S6ptk0

Comment: keep "CURLOPT_FAILONERROR: false" to get an error response body and then check HTTP status from "curl_getinfo($crl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)" based on the HTTP status you can return error or success.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at `curl_error`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: if you look at the comments you see he dont means that